# Flutter ListTile leading image and title alignment

Tags: listview, flutter, alignment

In a standard ListTile, is it possible to align the leading image and the title to be at the top, levelled?

```
 child: ListTile(
    leading: FlutterLogo(size: 72.0),
    title: Text('Three-line ListTile'),
    subtitle: Text(
      'A sufficiently long subtitle warrants three lines.'
    ),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
    isThreeLine: true,
  ),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html

Comment: What do you mean by "at the top, levelled"?

Comment: @FilipP. kind of like flashed at the top

Comment: Above subtitle? Like in a column?

Comment: @FilipP. it is like making the leading image and the title to be aligned at the top.

Comment: Wrap it in a container , give it a width and height and set alignment property.

Answer (score 1):

Use Transform try this

```
leading: Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0, -8),
              child: Container(
                height: 32,
                width: 32,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6)),
                  color: ThemeColor.lightGrey,
                ),
                child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person_fill),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using a `Row` widget as said in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html#material.ListTile.4) of the `ListTile` you should use a `Row` for example to achieve complex UIs.
In your case you need a `Row` with property `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 20,
        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/avatar1.jpg'),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'hello :  ',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text:
                          'the comment comment the comment comment the comment comment comment comment the comment comment the comment comment',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```